# Attaching a file to PHPMailer

Tags: php, blob, phpmailer, mailer

I am currently working on a project that has files stored in a DB as blobs. I need to attach the file to an e-mail and send it out via PHPMailer. I am familiar with `$mail->addAttachment()`, however, this function seems to take in a file path only, which I don't have. I was wondering if there is any way to manipulate the blob and feed to this function ?

I appreciate any suggestions, thanks in advance!

The following successfully creates a 'Save As' dialog of the file I need to attach:

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}.{$file_ext}");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
echo $pdf['data'];
exit;
```

Comment: The most obvious solution is to save the blob to a file.

Comment: Musa, thanks for the reply, yes, I was thinking: Save the file, attached the file, send the e-mail, then delete the file. However, seems a bit overkill. If there isn't a more straightforward direct solution, thats the one i'll go with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`addStringAttachment`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment) method is capable of handling such case. According to its doc:

> ```
> * Add a string or binary attachment (non-filesystem).
> * This method can be used to attach ascii or binary data,
> * such as a BLOB record from a database.
> ```